# Unit testing Angular directive, controller runs twice, first time with wrong scope

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

This is a weird one.

I have a directive that basically looks like this:

```
    function Toolbar() {
    return {
        scope:{
            resultType: '=',              
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'ToolbarController',
        controllerAs: 'toolbar',
        templateUrl: 'toolbar.html'
    };
}
```

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
function ToolbarController($scope, $stateParams) {
    var that = this;
    that.key = $stateParams.key;

    switch (that.resultType){
        case 'r':
            that.flag = false;
            break;
        default :
            vm.flag = true;
            break;
    }
 }
```

I have a test that looks like this:

```
it('should show the the correct flag', function() {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.resultType = 'r';
        toolbarController = $controller('ToolbarController', {$scope: scope, 
    $stateParams: $stateParams});
            expect(toolbarController.flag).toBe(false);
        });
```

When I just the test the controller seems to execute twice. The first time my response type is undefined and my test fails. The second time it's right, but by then the test has already failed.

Anybody seen this before and know what the problem is?

Thanks,
James

Comment: In your test are you testing the directive AND the controller or are you just testing a controller that happens to be used by a directive?

Comment: probably not related to your issue, but in the default section of your switch shouldn't the reference to vm.flag be that.flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sigh]

Found the problem. Someone had added a beforeEach where they created an instance of the toolbar and assigned it to an instance variable that used the same name as my local variable.

Off to murder^ someone, thanks!

^ Not literally, although I'm tempted.

Answer (score 0):

for testing angularJS driective controllers using `bindToController`, you have to pass your bound items to `$controller` as a third parameter, something like this:

```
toolbarController = $controller('ToolbarController', {$scope: scope, 
$stateParams: $stateParams}, { resultType: 'r' });
```

see the angularJS documentation for [$controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller) for more

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried, got the same result. Just to verify I added a "throw" above the switch statement that outputs the value of resultType. The first time it is undefined, the second time it is the letter 'r'.